# SwiftUI Stepper EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on Mac (designed for iPhone) works ok in iOS sim or real device

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

The problem lies when trying to use any Stepper() and having the supported destinations to include Mac ( designed for iPhone ) and running it on the Mac. On the iPhone / iOS real device of course the stepper works ok.

The problem is it just gives a BAD_EXC_ACCESS error.

Please take a look at:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730554

This is happening on Sonoma 14.1.2, Xcode 15. iOS deployment target at 16.0.

I don't know if there's a way to check if the app is running in that compatibility mode on the Mac and if so, have an alternative for Stepper() so it doesn't crash.

---

This is exactly what's happening to me and to this guy over the at Apple dev thread. Basically I can't use any Stepper when running the native iOS app on the Mac.

---

From the developer forum post:

> Here is code that presents the issue:

> ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var someValue = 5
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Stepper", value: $someValue, in: 0...10)
        }
    }
}
```

> When run from Xcode on an iOS device or the simulator, it runs fine.

> Trying to run it on the Mac, it crashes here:

> Stepper_01App.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main // <-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16a643f70)
struct Stepper_01App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

> Xcode 14.3 (14E222b), macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a), Mac mini M2. Target: Mac (Designed for iPhone).

> We have verified that the same code crashes on all the Apple Silicon Macs we have access to. Searching the Internet and Apple Developer forums I don't find other reports, so I kind of feel there must be some level of either user error or system/project misconfiguration going on?

> If any iOS app that used Steppers was just crashing when trying to run on a Mac, it seems like this would be a big deal.

> If anyone has input or can point out what we need to do differently, it would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are able to recreate the problem reliably with a [mcve] then I suggest you consider using one of your paid support incidents that come with your developer program membership.

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 just did that yesterday as well! Thanks for suggesting!  .. im waiting on their side

Comment: im seeing how to circumvent the problem, If you Add IPAD as a destination, Mac destination becomes "designed for iPad" the Stepper will reproduce ok the Mac and works ok, But now your app has the iPad layout feeling etc, in my real project is messing my whole layout, if you only have iPhone and Mac a destination it becomes "designed for iPhone" and the stepper doesn't work, it crashes the app

Comment: im sending this to someone inside apple and he will be looking into this.. he got in touch... so lets see

Answer (score 0):

Answer on how to Prevent this from happening while your app is running on the Mac. we came up with after digging and having an inside hand from @eskimo at Apple.

1st step is to create a custom stepper ( if you need me to post some code on this, let me know )

2nd step and it is where magic is, have this var initialize on your view struct where you  are using the stepper

```
   private var isiOsAppOnMac :Bool = false
    
    init(comparaitem: comparaItem) {
        self.comparaitem = comparaitem
        self.isiOsAppOnMac = ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac
        
      }
```

and then , where the stepper will be use is just a matter of :

```
if isiOsAppOnMac { 

CustomStepper()

} else {
// Native stepper
Stepper()

}
```

also you can just use where you want to check if is running on Mac and then throw the custom stepper

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {
//custom

CustomStepper()

} else {

//native

Stepper()

}
```

I ll throw my custom stepper code as a bonus.

-- CustomStepper.swift

```
// Custom Stepper ButtonStyle    
struct CustomStepperButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
           
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill((configuration.isPressed ? Color.gray.opacity(0.3) : Color(hex: colorScheme == .light ? "eaeaeb" : "262629")!
                          )).scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                )
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2),value:configuration.isPressed)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1.0) // Optional: Apply scale effect on press
            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
           
    }
}

struct CustomStepper<Content: View>: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    //@Binding var value: Int
    let onIncrement: (() -> Void)?
    let onDecrement: (() -> Void)?
    let label : Content
    
    // animation Variables
    @State private var didTapMinus = false
    @State private var didTapPlus = false
    
    
    init( onIncrement: (() -> Void)? = nil, onDecrement: (() -> Void)? = nil, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Content) {
        
        self.label = label()
        self.onIncrement = onIncrement
        self.onDecrement = onDecrement
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            label
                .foregroundColor(.comparaUIMaterialRedColor)
            
            HStack(spacing:0) {
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    // self.value -= self.step
                    
                    
                    didTapMinus.toggle()
                    self.onDecrement?()
                    
                    
            
                    
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Spacer()
                    }.frame(width:38,height:32)
                    
                      
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(CustomStepperButtonStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.comparaUIMaterialRedColor)
                
                
                
                // Divider
                Divider()
                    .padding(.vertical,5)
                    .padding(.horizontal,2)
                
                Button(action: {
                    // self.value += self.step
                    
                    didTapPlus.toggle()
                    self.onIncrement?()
                                           
                    
                }) {
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Spacer()
                        
                        
                    }.frame(width:38,height:32)
                        
                  
                      
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(CustomStepperButtonStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.comparaUIMaterialRedColor)
                
                
                
                
            }
            .padding(0)
            
            .frame(height:32)
            .background {
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color(hex: colorScheme == .light ? "eaeaeb" : "262629")!)
            }.mask {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
}
```